# How to match svg element ids with json keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, svg

I have an svg [(can be viewed here)](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/c3f7ea250a2039c9edca0b12a530f108d6304e1c/picture.svg) to which I would like to present some data on click. The Data is in json format and I would like to match each id of svg element with key in [json data](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/c3f7ea250a2039c9edca0b12a530f108d6304e1c/data.json) if both of these are same then do something. For example if Json key is key: china and element id is china then present information of china from json. I have already extracted the desired format of data I just cannot figure out how to match these keys with the element ids.

This is how I am accessing the dataset

```
 var countriesByName = d3.nest()
            .key(function (d) {
            return d.Country_Names;
        })


             .entries(data);
        // creating dropdown
        var data = JSON.stringify(countriesByName)
        var data = JSON.parse(data);

//this is the key I would like to match with element ids:

    var keys = function( d ) {
                return d.key;
            }
```

From this the format of json changes to

```
    [{"key":"Albania",
   "values":  [{"Continent":"Europe",
               "Country_Names":"Albania",
                "Total":"3.8",
                 "Change_total":"-38.7",
               "Main activity electricity and heat production":"0.1",
                "Main activity electricity plants":"",
                "Main activity CHP plants":"","Unallocated autoproducers / Other energy industry own use":"0.1",
            "Other":"1.4",
            "Manufacturing industries and construction":"1",
             "Iron and steel":"0",
          "Chemical and petrochemical":"0",
           "Machinery":"",
          "Mining and quarrying":"",
          "Food and tobacco":"0.1",
         "Paper, pulp and printing":"",
         "Construction":"0",
         "Transport":"2.2",
         "Road":"2.2",
          "Domestic aviation":"",
          "Rail":"0",
         "Domestic navigation":"0.1",
           "Residential":"0.2",
          "Commercial and public services":"0",
         "Agriculture/forestry":"0.2",
          "Sub-bituminous coal / Lignite":"",
          "Other bituminous coal":"",
          "Natural gas":"0",
         "Motor gasoline excl. bio":"0.3",
         "Gas/diesel oil excl. bio":"2.2"}]}
```

**fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n5v84svm/47/**

Comment: Although I have seen your code before, I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. Where in your JSFiddle do you want the matching to take place?

Comment: @altocumulus: where the fill is taking place, because fill right now do not present the correct data of countries

Comment: As I wrote to Arvind before here is what I am trying to achieve:  I have an svg graphic, you can see it in the fiddle, each path in the graphic has a specific id which is the name of country the path reprsents now I want to fill the paths with colors reprensenting data of the country see json above, How can I tell my code to look at the id of th eelement and match it with dataset if key (which has country names) equals id then take the data for that element.

Comment: Ah, now it becomes clear. There are several questions around on SO dealing with this. See [my favourite answer](/a/14150354/4235784) for a good explanation.

Comment: @altocumulus Thanks a lot again for your answer now it returns a black fill I think this is because I cannot get values.Total.. can I use map function for this?

Comment: Well, that may be worth a new question. I am still not sure what is going on when binding your data. Why are you doing a `JSON.stringify()` followed by a `JSON.parse()`. `countriesByName` will hold exactly this array in the first place. Also, why are you binding `data_clean` instead of `countriesByName` which contains all the properties you need? If you have further problems, please post a new question.

Comment: maybe by using keys.hasownproperty(id)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the JSON data from the remote URL, then you can filter with any key value to get the particular data object form the data source. Please check the below code. Apologies if My solution is wrong for your problem.

```
//Get Data from the Remote URL
    var countryData=$.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/c3f7ea250a2039c9edca0b12a530f108d6304e1c/data.json");  
countryData=JSON.parse(countryData.responseText);
//this is the key I would like to match with element ids:
var keys = function( d ) {
    var keyData=data.filter(function(value) {   return value.Country_Names == d;});
    return keyData;     
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but have already extracted the keys I just cannot figure out how can I match these keys with element ids of my svg

Comment: Sorry for wrong solution to you. Could you please clarify me the exact thing that you want?

Comment: No need to say sorry at all, thank you for trying. I will try to explain a bit more: I have an svg graphic, you can see it in the fiddle, each path in the graphic has a specific id which is the name of country the path reprsents now I want to fill the paths with colors reprensenting data of the country see json above, How can I tell my code to look at the id of th eelement and match it with dataset if key (which has country names) equals id then take the data for that element.

Comment: hope that explains a bit more